# How to equally distribute processing of Azure Service Bus Queue across multiple instances?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I've been working on this for last 24 hours.

I'm using WorkerRoleWithSBQueue Visual Studio template.

PrefetchCount is set to 0.

I even tried with OnMessageOptions() { MaxConcurrentCalls = 1 };

Yesterday I had two instances and it seemed like it is using both of them equally. Meaning that if I send two requests at once it will use both instances to process messages.

Now I raised number of instances to 10 and I'm back to the drawing board. I send 10 messages, each message takes ~ 15 seconds to complete. Somehow single instance takes two messages at once, meaning that an instance that should be working doesn't have a message to work on.

I have a deadline for Dec 11th and I'm starting to panic a bit.

Have any of you had any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you measure this with higher number of messages ? My only question is - how do you know that ServiceBus is the culprit and not your role instances pulling the data less frequently ? In an average case - ServiceBus delivers uniformly.

Setting prefetchCount=0 should be the way to tell ServiceBus to recv. absolutely only one message - but in my view - it might not be the right way to achieve uniform distributed processing. You are taking a performance hit (n/w calls) by doing so - which the application will experience particularly when the queue size is big and receivers are lagging behind to process messages.
Instead I would suggest coming up with a strategy to distribute the messages among the roles.

One such strategy is to use Sessions - if you know that the receivers will always be a constant number and are sure that the traffic is uniformly distributed across all session id's:
 - Have all of your message producers assign a SessionId to the messages - lets say 1-10
 - On the receiver side - use [AcceptMessageSession(sessionId)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.acceptmessagesession.aspx)

If you feel that Sessions doesn't fit your need - feel free to give a high-level overview of your scenario. I can try n suggest a good way to achieve it.

HTH!
Sree